# C++ member array of struct thread safe using only one index per thread ?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is a C++ member array of struct thread safe using only one index per thread?

using the following class:

```
typedef struct {
    bool bFlag;
    unsigned int uiNum;
} TC_MYSTRUCT;

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    int GetFreeIndex();
    void SetIndexDataNum(int idx, int num);
    int GetIndexDataNum(int idx);
private:
    TC_MYSTRUCT m_arr[10];
};
```

- this class is defined as a global var.
- GetFreeIndex() is synchronized with critical section ...
- there are some threads getting a free index from the member array with GetFreeIndex()
- SetIndexDataNum modifies it's own unique entry within m_arr.
- within a thread SetIndexDataNum/GetIndexDataNum are called only with the thread specific index
- SetIndexDataNum/GetIndexDataNum can be called at the same time, but with different index
- SetIndexDataNum/GetIndexDataNum are never called at the same time within a thread

**Is it thread safe to use methods SetIndexDataNum/GetIndexDataNum without a critical section inside?** (since the are addressing only a specific array index)

Comment: You should have explain it better like giving more code or precisely write what is going on there. That what you suggested in a present code conflicts with that what you are writing later in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If `GetFreeIndex` is correctly synchronized, and never returns the same index twice, and a given index value is **never** shared between threads then calls to `SetIndexDataNum` and `GetIndexDataNum` do not require synchronization if they are simple array index operations, as separate threads are accessing separate objects.

If the index values are shared across threads then you will definitely need synchronization. If the get/set functions are more complex than a simple array index then they may need synchronization anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, SetIndexDataNum can be called with same index from more than one flow at the same time, then it is not thread-safe.

Separate critical sections should be maintained for each index in order to reduce time to wait.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if SetIndexDataNum/GetIndexDataNum modify any member of the class? I guess they do.

If they do, then it is not safe without Critical Section.

Comment: SetIndexDataNum/GetIndexDataNum are only called within the thread with the thread specific index and they are only modifying TC_MYSTRUCT members.

Comment: So, SetIndexDataNum modifies it's own unique entry within m_arr? If that is the case, then there needs to be a critical section to synchronize SetIndexDataNum and GetIndexDataNum

Comment: So if each thread has it's own TC_MYSTRUCT based on thread index then you don't need any synchronization at all.

Comment: yes, SetIndexDataNum modifies it's own unique entry within m_arr. and in addition: GetIndexDataNum is also called only within the same thread: so SetIndexDataNum/GetIndexDataNum are never called at the same time for a specific index

Comment: But there is a global variable of your class which is shared across your threads. It requires synchronizing SetIndexDataNum/GetIndexDataNum as they both write/read the same memory location i.e. m_arr[someindex];

Comment: @chubsdad: well i am wronng here. Set and Get are not called at the same time. So no need to synchronize.

Comment: SetIndexDataNum/GetIndexDataNum can be called at the same time, but with different index

Comment: Yes, since a thread can be calling either Set or Get of the global object, synchronizing them is not required.

Answer (score 0):

If they are just referring to "locked" cell then yes. But it should be designed a litter different. Your thread safe class should have two methods - one that acquires a resource that a thread would use freely and second - to release a resource. All operations on a resource should be accessible from it, not from the `MyClass`. You should be forced to "lock" a resource before you can use it:

```
struct TC_MYSTRUCT {
    bool bFlag;
    unsigned int uiNum;
    void Action();
};

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    TC_MYSTRUCT *GetFreeResource();
    void ReleaseResource(TC_MYSTRUCT *resource);
private:
    TC_MYSTRUCT m_arr[10];
};

/* thread */
TC_MYSTRUCT *resource = my_class.GetFreeResource();
resource->Action();
my_class.ReleaseResource(resource);
```